# Upgrade Autofac Multitenant with ASP.NET Core 2.2 to ASP.NET Core 5

Tags: asp.net-core, autofac

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.2 application that is currently using following dependencies:

- Autofac.AspNetCore.Multitenant version 1.1.0
- Autofac.AspNetCore.Extensions version :1.0.2

I want to upgrade the application from from ASP.NET Core 2.2 to ASP.NET 5. Because of the new Generic `IHostBuilder` and using `AutofacServiceProviderFactory`, I am kind of lost as to how to go about building tenants in program.cs and add/remove at runtime.
In .NET Core 2.2 I am doing it as follows:

```
var webHost = CreateTenantWebHostBuilder(args)
    .UseAutofacMultiTenant()
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .Build();

using (var scope = webHost.Services.CreateScope())
{
    try
    {
        var applicationLifetime = scope.ServiceProvider
            .GetRequiredService<IApplicationLifetime>();
        var tenantStore = scope.ServiceProvider
            .GetRequiredService<ICustomTenantsStore>();

        await tenantStore.InitializeTenantsAsync(applicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
                       
    }
}

await webHost.RunAsync(cancelTokenSource.Token);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend taking some time to review some of the resources available.

- [The documentation has a walkthrough of multitenant setup in ASP.NET Core.](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html#multitenant-support)
- [The `Autofac.AspNetCore.Multitenant` repo has samples](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.AspNetCore.Multitenant/blob/v5.0.0/samples) which show how to deal with [registering the multitenant container factory](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.AspNetCore.Multitenant/blob/dfc226e28c55be956ef275882306d7aff3376db8/samples/Sandbox.AspNetCore5/Program.cs#L15), [setting up common dependencies](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.AspNetCore.Multitenant/blob/dfc226e28c55be956ef275882306d7aff3376db8/samples/Sandbox.AspNetCore5/Startup.cs#L22), and [using a static method to configure tenants](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.AspNetCore.Multitenant/blob/dfc226e28c55be956ef275882306d7aff3376db8/samples/Sandbox.Shared/MultitenantContainerSetup.cs#L13).

You're making quite a jump from .NET Core 2.2 to 5.0, so you're not going to be able to stay on the older Autofac versions. I'd recommend updating to the latest - you'll get updated compatibility support for .NET 5, bug fixes, some perf improvements, and better troubleshooting support (among other things in the latest Autofac and extensions).

Comment: I agree it is a jump. I will first upgrade to 3.1 and the Autofac libs accordingly. It is just I was confused with the new Generic HostBuilder with regards to my implementation of " ITenantIdentificationStrategy".